# MCP 4725 with raspberry pi

Tags: circuit-analysis, raspberry-pi, i2c, dac

I have an MCP4725 12 bit DAC from Sparkfun and i  am trying to interface it with raspberry pi 3
  [image]

**Connections** :

Vcc -> 3.3V/5V of Rpi

Gnd ->Gnd of Rpi

scl and sda -> to scl and sda of rpi

out -> to DMM

and I tried to run this code: [ADAFRUIT](https://learn.adafruit.com/mcp4725-12-bit-dac-with-raspberry-pi/using-the-adafruit-library)

What else i tried :
I tried to short addr pin with vcc and then with Gnd
I also tried to cut the tracks from pullups thats are given on the back side of the board 
**Problem**

Even though I tried the connections ,The circuit does not seem to work .

**Questions** :

1)Is it possible to interface MCP4725 with Rpi ?
2)do I need to use level shifter for I2C pins ?

Comment: According to your URL: 1) Yes, 2) No

Comment: What is the connection for A0. You might be missing the address part. What is theI2C address of DAC you have configured for?. You didn't mention your problem. The interfaces are fine. Interfacing is obviously possible as the link is for the same from adafruit. No level shifters are necessary.

Comment: @Umar Well, there is no A0 pin on the board that I have I just have I2C pins.

Comment: Definitely do NOT cut the tracks to the pullup resistors!  You do know how i2c works, right?

Comment: what is the answer for my another question? what is the I2C address of DAC?

Comment: @Umar it looks like there is a solder jumper in the photograph he posted.  He says he tried it on both Vcc and Gnd.

Comment: @jhonny_boy I have 2-3 boards, I tried it on one of them and  I don't  know much about i2c interface, I also tried I2C detect .. I Did not get any address

Comment: i2c requires pullup resistors to work.  Please tell us exactly which pins you connected to on the raspi3.  Maybe you used the wrong pins.  If you can take a picture that would be even better.

Comment: I2C address assumed in the code is 0x62. Assuming this as 7 byte address, ADDR should be connected to GND. Since, you have already tried both combination of ADDR, we suspect on the connection. Did you monitor Clock and data line? do you have an oscilloscope?

Comment: @Umar I don't know the address, I tried to do I2C detect but it doesn't give any address

Comment: @johnny_boy  I connected the I2C pins from IC to 27/28 pins of Rpi 3. also I enabled the I2C from settings of Rpi3. and I don't have oscilloscope, only a small multimeter.

Comment: Please re look your connections. until you pass i2cdetect command successfully, you shouldn't proceed. measure the I2C voltage levels on SCL and SDA. . They should be high and same as VDD. independent of ADDR connection, the i2cdetect test should give you out the I2C address of the device. Else, you are still not ready with I2C modules on Pi OR connection issues.

Comment: @Umar Thankyou Umar! I take a look at it again and see if I get an address on I2C detect. I will review the connections again.

Comment: You are aware you have to enable the Raspberry Pi3 I2C unit by specifying dtparam=i2c_arm=on in config.txt? Uh, and the kernel modules bcm2708-i2c and i2c-dev should be loaded. Check with lsmod.

Comment: @Janka This i did not know, i will check those things asap !

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, you can use MCP4725 with rpi.
2. Yes, IF you power your MCP4725 with 5V0.
3. The devices addresses are 0x62/0x63 for A0 = 0/1
4. The on board pull up resistors are 4k7.  You need to remove them IF you have too many other I2C devices connected.